# Azure VM - registry change prevents booting machine

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

We applied some Azure security center recommendations to our registry. A incorrect change in `HKLM\SOFTWARE` caused two machines to no longer boot `(CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED)`.

We took a snapshot of the osdisk and attached that to a different VM and cleaned that up. Confirmed after restoring     `C:\windows\system32\config\regback\software` to `C:\windows\system32\config\software` fixes the issue.

The disks are encrypted however so Azure won't allow us to perform an `OSdisk swap` between the current corrupted osdisk and the fixed one.

[image]

Since the VM isn't bootable, we can't disable the encryption either from Azure portal.

[image]

- Is there a way we can boot an Azure VM from it last succesful state without having a Azure backup available? or
- Is there a way to perform an OSdisk swap with keeping the osdisk encrypted? or
- Is there a way we can force the Azure VM to use the `regback` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your actual question, but one thing you can do for sure is just create a new vm from the working disk. You can create a VM from existing encrypted disk if you give it keys to decrypt it.

Comment: I wanted to avoid deploying a new VM as, the VM was deployed through lcs.Dynamics.com and we aren't sure what's it all attached to. 
Yeah, seems there's no way yet to fix a VM with encrypted disks.And this will be our only option
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/37522534-support-osdisk-swap-for-encrypted-vms